# Proving $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}\right) +\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}\right)\\$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Prove that

$$e^{i\theta}\cdot\frac{e^{in\theta}-1}
{e^{i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}\right) +\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}\right)\\$$

---

I tried to use $$ e^{in\theta} =\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$ but with this way I got a big expression with cos(n*x)*sin^2(x)..... So. I'm lost.

Comment: Who told you that this was true?

Comment: This is equivalent to proving
$$ \cos \theta + \cos 2\theta + \cdots + \cos n\theta + i(\sin \theta + \sin 2\theta + \cdots + \sin n\theta) = \cos n\theta + \sin n\theta$$
Is an $i$ missing on the RHS? And even then it doesn't look right.

Comment: In fact, it's easy to see that an $i$ is missing (or extra). For $n = 1$, the LHS becomes $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, and the RHS becomes $\sin \theta + \cos \theta$. If the question could be correct at all, then the denominator of the first term on the RHS should be $2$ instead of $2i$.

Comment: If the $i$ in the RHS is removed, it becomes (on equating the real and imaginary parts):
$$ \cos \theta + \cos 2\theta + \cdots + \cos n\theta = \cos n\theta\\
\sin \theta + \sin 2\theta + \cdots + \sin n\theta = \sin n\theta $$
which is obviously false in the general case.

Comment: You've edited it, but it's still not correct (look at the example in heropup's comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivially false:  simply take $n = 1$, $\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: It (the case in your example) would be correct if the $i$ in the denominator of the RHS were removed.

Comment: Then $n = 2$ is yet another counterexample--we can even take $\theta = \pi$ in such a case to make calculation even easier.